# Concatenating through a loop articles in Python

Tags: python, loops

I want to create the corpus by concatenating all the articles (body) in my file.

```
for i in range(len(data) -1):
    corpus = data[i]['body'] + data[i+1]['body']
print(corpus)
```

As you I imagined I only get the last two articles together. Any idea of how to get all of them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
corpus = []
for i in range(len(data) -1):
    corpus.append(data[i]['body'] + data[i+1]['body'])
print(corpus)
```

Answer (score 2):

Each iteration you're overwriting the previous value of `corpus`. Concatenate them all together.

```
corpus = ''
for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    corpus += data[i]['body']
```

This could be simplified by iterating over `data` directly.

```
corpus = ''
for d in data:
    corpus += d['body']
```

Or better yet, use `str.join` with a generator expression to do it all in one line.

```
corpus = ''.join(d['body'] for d in data)
```

Answer (score -1):

The print statement is outsite the loop. Place it inside and you are good to go